# Same controller for different url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Im developing an application using Spring. I want to map some different url to the same controller, an UserController, where I have a method to add an user, and another method to retrieve an user from the database. So, I did a Controller that looks like that:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController{

String name;
String pass;
@Autowired
UsuarioService usuarioService;




@RequestMapping("/usuario/adduser")
public String addUsuario(){
    System.out.println("url adduser");
    return name;

}

@RequestMapping("/usuario/getbyid")
public String getById(){
    System.out.println("url getbyid");
    return name;
}

}
```

And I have the urls mapped this way in the root-context.xml:

```
<bean name="logincontroller" class="com.desarrollo.helpin.Controllers.LoginController"/>
<!--  <bean name="simpleUrlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/newuserform">newuserformcontroller</prop>
            <prop key="/logincontroller">logincontroller</prop>
            <prop key="/quees">queescontroller</prop>
             <prop key="/adduser">logincontroller</prop> 
            <prop key="/getbyid">logincontroller</prop>
        </props>

    </property>
    </bean>-->
```

I got two buttons in the home.jsp, one with the url "/usuario/getbyid" and another with url "/usuario/adduser".

Doing this, none of the system.out.println in the two methods of the controller shows up. How could I achieve this goal?

Thank you.

EDIT:

The web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If I am not in a mistake, the DispatcherServlet loads servlet-context.xml. Here is it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<!--<annotation-driven />-->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />


</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.development.testing" />
```

Comment: do have two bean cofiguration file in your app?

Comment: When I created the project I used a wizard, and created a root-context and a servlet-context

Comment: then remove login controller bean from root-context.xml, move it to servlet-context.xml OR as you using annotation-drivern, declare component-scan and give base-package location of your controller package name/root package, it will work

Comment: I put the logincontroller bean to the servlet-context.xml and now I am receiving an java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'loginController' bean method 
public java.lang.String com.desarrollo.helpin.Controllers.LoginController.getById()
to {[/usuario/getbyid],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'logincontroller' bean method
public java.lang.String com.desarrollo.helpin.Controllers.LoginController.getById() mapped.

Comment: have you removed loginController from root-context.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` that isn't going to work with a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`. Also wouldn't it be a bit pointless to specify the URL in the `@RequestMapping` and again have to define them in your configuration.

Instead of the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` add the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to your context. Note this has to be done in the context that is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` not the one loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. The `DispatcherServlet` is using it's own application context (and not the parent from the `ContextLoaderListener` to configure itself).

Comment: Still not working. I add that line and commented the lines involving the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping. After dealing with "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element mvc:annotation-driven" error, I had it apparently working. But still the sysouts are not shown. If I set "<form action="usuario/adduser"> and "action=usuario/getbyid" int the jsp, and "@RequestMapping("usuario/adduser")" and "usuario/getbyid" now I get a warn( In the next comment)

Comment: "org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/testing/usuario/adduser] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'". Sounds like it is trying to find a JSP, but it does not pass through the Controller.

Comment: As mentioned the configuration must be done in the one loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` not the one loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`.  Please add the web.xml to your original post.

Comment: Question updated. I have added also the context loaded by the DispatcherServlet.

Comment: I would suspect that your controller isn't loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. However as you haven't specified the actual packages that is hard to tell. Enable *DEBUG* logging for spring to see what is detected and what not and how the request gets handled.

Comment: I have updated the question with the actual packages.

Comment: Yuor controller is loaded by the `ContextLoader` and as such not detected by the `DispatcherServlet` (or to be more precise by the `RequestMethodHandlerMapping`). You must move it to your other configuration. Everything web related should be under control of your `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: As you can see, I am very novice with Spring. I would really appreciate a more precise answer. You mean I have to move the bean declaration of LoginControllerr to the servlet-context.xml?

Comment: Done that. I have now an org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'loginController' bean method 
public java.lang.String com.desarrollo.helpin.Controllers.LoginController.getById(). But as far as I know I have not mapped it elsewhere. I am gonna cry...

Comment: Is your component-scan also picking up the controller? If so you have 2 instances.

Comment: This is my component-scan: <context:component-scan base-package="com.desarrollo.helpin" /> in both context. I have now commented the one at root-context.xml, and still receiving that error.

Comment: Remove the bean declaration. You already have the bean due to the component-scanning. So no need to declare it again. As mentioned before enable **DEBUG** logging for `org.springframework` and see what happens.

Comment: But I have not the homeController declared enywhere, so I cant remove that bean. And how could I enable DEBUG logging for org.springframework? As I told you, im pretty new to Spring. I feel I am wasting your time, Deinum, please forgive me but im desperated...

Comment: You have added it to the `servlet-context.xml` and have a `component-scan`. Both lead to an instance of the bean, hence 2 instances. First simplify things, ditch the `ContextLoaderListener` you don't need it right now. Put everything in the `DispatcherServlet`, how to enable debug logging depends on which logging framework you use (log4j, logback, ...). Check the reference guide as that has tons of information.